# How to use 2 angularjs apps in same html page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to use 2 angularjs apps in same html page?

Here is the code to reproduce, where 2nd app fails:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});

var app1 = angular.module("myApp1", []);
app1.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John1";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe1";
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also I have tried to use `angular.bootstrap` with no luck like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311908/using-two-angularjs-apps-in-one-page)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>


<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);


var app1 = angular.module("myApp1", []);

app1.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John1";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe1";
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp1']);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="firstApp" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>

<div id="firstApp1" ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>


<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});

let appEl1 = document.getElementById("firstApp");
angular.bootstrap(appEl1, ['myApp']);


var app1 = angular.module("myApp1", []);

app1.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John1";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe1";
});

let appEl2 = document.getElementById("firstApp1");
angular.bootstrap(appEl2, ['myApp1']);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

Comment: Inject one app inside other app.. in other words, make one root app. will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are bootstrapping both apps on `document`. It needs to be on the element(`div` in your case) that you want it to be according to [angular.bootstrap documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Eg:

```
<div id="firstApp">

let appEl1 = document.getElementById("firstApp");
angular.bootstrap(appEl1, ['myFirstApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("appID"), ['myApp1']);
```

with

```
<div id="appID" ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
```

This will bootstrap it manually.

(You also had a typo(?) in your first case with registering a controller: `app.controller("myCtrl1"` should be `app1.controller("myCtrl1"`)